# Latest build.xml for building Android with ant and aspectJ

Tags: android, ant, aspectj, build.xml

I'm a newbie in Android develop.

Now there is an urgent work need I to use aspectJ develop an Android project, and use Ant to build the apk.

I found this project: https://code.google.com/p/android-aspectj/

But the build.xml is too old to work with SDK r16.

I'm not familiar with Ant script; is there any place I can find an new version build.xml can work with SDK r16 and aspectJ?

Thanks.

I changed some obvious places in the build.xml
now:

Error. You are using an obsolete build.xml
You need to delete it and regenerate it using
        android update project

```
    at com.android.ant.SetupTask.execute(SetupTask.java:42)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:795)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

    Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: do you know what exactly does not work? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: first, it said: com.android.ant.AaptExecLoopTask not found. So I change it to : `<taskdef name="aaptexec"
 classname="com.android.ant.AaptExecTask"
 classpathref="android.antlibs"/>` now, it said `Error. You are using an obsolete build.xml
You need to delete it and regenerate it using
        android update project`